# pytest LogCaptureHandler for child logger object with propagate = False

Tags: python, logging, pytest

In my python application I use child loggers for each module with propagate=False.
(This is because I have a custom Formatter for each child logger objects, and since the the application is expected to write logs to the stdout and since I do not want duplicate logs I set propagate = False. So I explicitly set StreamHanlder to the child loggers and do not set any handler to the root logger.)

The problem I face is while running pytest. Apparently pytest does not capture the logs emitted by child loggers with propagate = False.

What options do I have here if I want the logs emitted by the child loggers to be captured by pytest?

Thanks for the suggestions.